# Datanuclues error when compiling appengine backend on android studio

Tags: android, google-app-engine, ubuntu, android-studio, datanucleus

I am using android studio on Ubuntu and have been trying to set-up Google App Engine Backend. Here is my pom.xml file, I have tried to use the latest version of all dependencies and plugins.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <groupId>com.watch.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>watch-AppEngine</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <appengine.target.version>1.8.9</appengine.target.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Compile/runtime dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>${appengine.target.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-endpoints</artifactId>
            <version>${appengine.target.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0-alpha-1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
            <artifactId>geronimo-jpa_2.0_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jsr107cache</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr107cache</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
            <artifactId>datanucleus-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine.orm</groupId>
            <artifactId>datanucleus-appengine</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
            <artifactId>datanucleus-api-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ganyo</groupId>
            <artifactId>gcm-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-testing</artifactId>
            <version>${appengine.target.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-api-stubs</artifactId>
            <version>${appengine.target.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <!-- for hot reload of the web application-->
        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/WEB-INF/classes
        </outputDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webXml>
                        ${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/appengine-endpoints/WEB-INF/web.xml
                    </webXml>
                    <webResources>
                        <resource>
                            <!-- this is relative to the pom.xml directory -->
                            <directory>
                                ${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/appengine-endpoints
                            </directory>
                            <!-- the list has a default value of ** -->
                            <includes>
                                <include>WEB-INF/*.discovery</include>
                                <include>WEB-INF/*.api</include>
                            </includes>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
                <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.8.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <enableJarClasses>false</enableJarClasses>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>endpoints_get_discovery_doc</goal>
                            <!--goal>endpoints_get_client_lib</goal-->
                            <goal>enhance</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Java version : 
dexter@dexter-Lenovo-G505s:~$ java -version
java version "1.8.0-ea"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0-ea-b108)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.0-b50, mixed mode)

Maven version :
Apache Maven 3.1.1 (0728685237757ffbf44136acec0402957f723d9a; 2013-09-17 20:52:22+0530)
Maven home: /home/dexter/Desktop/apache-maven-3.1.1
Java version: 1.8.0-ea, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0/jre
Default locale: en_IN, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.8.13-992-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"

When I try to perform a mvn compile, I get the following error :

> [ERROR] -------------------- [ERROR]  Standard error from the
>   DataNucleus tool + org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer :
>   [ERROR] -------------------- [ERROR] Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
>           at org.datanucleus.asm.ClassReader.(ClassReader.java:185)
>           at org.datanucleus.asm.ClassReader.(ClassReader.java:168)
>           at org.datanucleus.asm.ClassReader.(ClassReader.java:439)
>           at org.datanucleus.enhancer.jdo.JDOClassEnhancer.getClassNameForFileName(JDOClassEnhancer.java:172)
>           at org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer.getFileMetadataForInput(DataNucleusEnhancer.java:730)
>           at org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer.enhance(DataNucleusEnhancer.java:513)
>           at org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer.main(DataNucleusEnhancer.java:1281)

Here is a link to the full stack trace of the error(s): 
http://pastebin.com/bAeMZyeb

Please help me fix this problem, thank you for your patience.

Comment: so read the code for that line throwing the exception ? https://github.com/datanucleus/datanucleus-core/blob/master/src/java/org/datanucleus/asm/ClassReader.java#L185   Seems you're using JDK 1.8+ and the version of ASM in use only supports <=1.7. ASM v5 is not yet released

Comment: [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS

thanks a lot, in future ill keep in mind to check the code first.

Answer (score -2):

This got resolved itself.

This kind of issue occurs when the build is too latest and some changes are happening at the source location. Trying again after 10 minutes resolved this issue for me and the build was successful with the latest appengine.target.version.